# How to use alias column in lag function

Tags: postgresql

How can i use alias column `sisa` to lag function in case statement

```
select i.item_name , i.item_code, DATE(ic.transaction_date), doc_no, qty,
case when count(item_name) over(partition by item_name) = 1
        then sum(qty) over(partition by doc_no)
    else 
        case when row_number() over(partition by item_code) = 1
            then first_value(qty) over(partition by item_code)
            else
                qty + lag(sisa)over (partition by item_code)
        end
end as sisa
from item_card_today ic
join item i on i.item_id = ic.item_id
where transaction_date 
between '2019-03-31 00:11:42'::timestamp and '2019-04-02 08:17:35'::timestamp
and i.item_code = 'CLDXMZM3NTDGSHCKPRFHBHTM'
order by item_code asc, item_name asc
```

How i can use sisa in the code?

Comment: Maybe some sample data and desired results?

Comment: You should extract the CASE into a CTE in order to reference `sisa`